# Check if there's a cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I'm trying to find an algorithms that checks if there's a cycle in a given undirected graph G=(V,E).

But I didn't succeed.

Can anyone give me such an algorithm?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526331/cycles-in-an-undirected-graph
https://www.me.utexas.edu/~bard/IP/Handouts/cycles.pdf
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253716/algorithm-to-check-whether-a-graph-has-no-cycles

Comment: If you are not interested in finding the actual cycle, but just checking if there is a cycle you really don't need any complicated algorithm. Find a connected component and count the number of edges. If it is greater than or equal to the number of vertices in that connected component, there is a cycle in the connected component.